# Align text at ":" css?

Tags: html, css

Okay so I am making a list of attributes with html, using this method:

```
<h3 id="previewDesc">
    <span class="1">Item 1: </span><br>
    <span class="2">2: </span><br>
    <span class="3">Long item:</span>
</h3>
```

I want to align them all at the ":" if possible. What would be the best way to do this? (Doesn't have to be css but it is preferable)

Comment: `text-align: ':'` is not currently supported by any browser, but this will be the way to do it in future.

Comment: you could use a [monospace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font and put some non-breaking spaces to align manually http://jsfiddle.net/otpe1ys1/